# How to print hidden files/folders list using NAnt script?

Tags: nant, hidden-files

Current I try as below but that will skip all hidden files/folders. I want to see them.

Please help if you know the trick! Thank you.

```
<foreach item="Folder" property="folderName">
    <in>
        <items>
            <include name=".\**" />
        </items>
    </in>
    <do>
        <echo message="${folderName}" />
    </do>
</foreach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure they are skipped because they're hidden? I'm more inclined that the files not listed are in [default excludes](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/types/fileset.html). You should try disabling these excludes and see if that helps:

```
<foreach item="Folder" property="folderName">
    <in>
        <items defaultexcludes="false">
            <include name=".\**" />
        </items>
    </in>
    <do>
        <echo message="${folderName}" />
    </do>
</foreach>
```